# How to include your current locale into the url? (Nuxt.js/Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I need to include my locale (en/nl) into my url of my nuxt.js/vuetify project, i used i18n to translate. I tried using the built in dynamic routing feature, by prefixing an underscore in my directory name, for example, the folder _lang, includes the vue pages Index, Gallery & About Us. the feature promises that because of the underscore the url part for _lang can be anything.

For example: `localhost:3000/lang/gallery` can also be `localhost:3000/randomstring/gallery` it doesnt matter. i tried to get and set that "randomstring" by using the global routing variable `($route.params.[randomstring])`, i could only get it, not set it. So when i change locale (using i18n) the "randomstring" is cannot be set to the same name as the chosen locale.

My only work around was using the 'base' property of the vue-router component by hard coding the process environment variable after the default value ("/").

Another work around would be to duplicate all pages and hard code translate them into their respective folder (a folder 'en' and a folder 'nl' including all 3 pages). but this wouldn't be sustainable as you are adding pages to the site.

TL DR: How do you add a locale dynamically into your nuxt.js/vuetify project (using i18n)?

Used documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [nuxt/i18n](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/) module `localePath` method, your url will change accordingly to the current active locale.

```
<nuxt-link :to="localePath('about')">Go to about page</nuxt-link>.
```

Will redirect you to: `/fr/about` if 'fr' (French) is the active locale.

To set locale, use the `setLocale` method:

```
<button @click="$i18n.setLocale('fr')">Set Locale</button>
```

More nuxt/i18n API Reference can be found here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/api#methods-1